What is the correct way of extending an S3 class from another package in R
I am writing an R package pkgA that is extending another package, pkgB. In particular, I implemented a new class gas_planet that extends the functionality of a class planet written in pkgB. When I use devtools::load_all(), I have no problems in extending a generic function pkgB::hello() to hello.gas_planet(). However, when running devtools::check(), examples calling the generic function from pkgB halt with the following error:
> checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in 'pkgA-Ex.R' failed
  The error most likely occurred in:
  
  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: hello.gas_planet
  > ### Title: Say hello to a gas planet
  > ### Aliases: hello.gas_planet
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  > planet <- set_gas_planet("Jupiter")
  > hello(planet)
Error in hello(planet) : could not find function "hello"
Execution halted

The code from the mother package pkgB is:
#' Set planet
#'
#' @param name planet name
#'
#' @return planet object
#' @export
set_planet <- function(name){
  planet <- list(name = name)
  class(planet) <- "planet"
  return(planet)
}


#' Say hello to a planet
#'
#' @param planet a planet object
#' @param ... More arguments
#'
#' @export
hello <- function(planet, ...) {
  UseMethod("hello", planet)
}

with NAMESPACE
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(hello)
export(set_planet)

My child package pkgA contains the code:
#' Set gas planet
#'
#' @inheritParams pkgB::set_planet
#'
#' @return planet object
#' @export
set_gas_planet <- function(name){
  planet <- list(name = name, structure = "rocky")
  class(planet) <- c("gas_planet", "planet")
  return(planet)
}

#' Say hello to a gas planet
#'
#' @inheritParams pkgB::hello
#'
#' @import pkgB
#'
#' @examples
#' planet <- set_gas_planet("Jupiter")
#' hello(planet)
#'
#' @export
hello.gas_planet <- function(planet, ...) {
  print(paste0("Hello, ", planet$name, "! You look breezy today."))
}

with NAMESPACE file
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(hello,gas_planet)
export(set_gas_planet)
import(pkgB)


From this post, I learned that @importFrom is not needed. In any case, switching from @import pkgB to @importFrom pkgB did not solve the problem.
The solution I came up with after reading above mentionned post is adding @export hello below @export in the specification of hello.gas_planet(). This makes the error message disappear but instead, I get the warning:
> checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
  Undocumented code objects:
    'hello'
  All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
  See chapter 'Writing R documentation files' in the 'Writing R
  Extensions' manual.

Writing a documentation for a generic function from another package appears to me as an unnecessary and possibly dangerous redundancy. What is the correct way of inheriting S3 generics from another package without getting any problems in devtools::check()?
EDIT:
For reproducing the error, I created two GitHub repositories for pkgA and pkgB. I produced the error on Windows 10 and Windows 11 using R 4.3.1 and 4.3.3, respectively. I installed both packages locally. The error occurs when using devtools::check() or after installing the package using devtools::install(). Running the examples after using devtools::load_all() works fine.

Can you call other functions from pkgB in your examples? It seems like the import is not working. Are you developing both packages locally? Are you sure you have the current versions installed? Do you have this as part of github repo we can checkout and test with? Also see https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html#functions-1. If you just use @imports, you want to use pkgB::hello() If you want just hello() then use @importFrom

I cannot reproduce the error, the posted code works fine with me.

Thank you very much for the reply. I added some information on how to reproduce the error.

I found a fix for the problem, see answer below. I do not really understand why attaching is necessary and importing is not enough. I will accept another answer explaining the problem in more detail.

The issue is that you are calling the unqualified hello() function in your example. But the example is executed in the global namespace, and you didn’t attach ‘pkgB’, nor did you reexport pkgB::hello() from ‘pkgA’. So it’s not visible in the global namespace. That’s why your example fails.
To fix this, either (import and) reexport pkgB::hello() from ‘pkgA’, or explicitly qualify hello() in the example as pkgB::hello().
To reexport a name (such as an S3 generic) from another package, use
#' @importFrom pkgB hello
#' @export
pkgB::hello

This way you also don’t need a general @import pkgB directive.
(There’s unfortunately a bug in the current version (7.3.1) of ‘roxygen2’ which generates an incorrect NAMESPACE directive for S3 methods of imported generics (namely, export(), whereas we want S3method()). To work around this, either use @exportS3Method pkgB::hello, or run devtools::document() multiple times until the NAMESPACE is no longer updated.)
Here’s the complete code for pkgA/R/hello.R:
#' @importFrom pkgB hello
#' @export
pkgB::hello

#' Set gas planet
#'
#' @inheritParams pkgB::set_planet
#'
#' @return planet object
#' @export
set_gas_planet <- function(name) {
  planet <- list(name = name, structure = "rocky")
  class(planet) <- c("gas_planet", "planet")
  planet
}

#' Say hello to a gas planet
#'
#' @inheritParams pkgB::hello
#'
#' @examples
#' planet <- set_gas_planet("Jupiter")
#' hello(planet)
#'
#' @export
hello.gas_planet <- function(planet, ...) {
  print(paste0("Hello, ", planet$name, "! You look breezy today."))
}


Alternatively, here’s the solution without reexporting pkgB::hello():
#' Set gas planet
#'
#' @inheritParams pkgB::set_planet
#'
#' @return planet object
#' @export
set_gas_planet <- function(name) {
  planet <- list(name = name, structure = "rocky")
  class(planet) <- c("gas_planet", "planet")
  planet
}

#' Say hello to a gas planet
#'
#' @inheritParams pkgB::hello
#'
#' @examples
#' planet <- set_gas_planet("Jupiter")
#' pkgB::hello(planet)
#'
#' @importFrom pkgB hello
#' @export
hello.gas_planet <- function(planet, ...) {
  print(paste0("Hello, ", planet$name, "! You look breezy today."))
}


Hi Konrad, thank you for the reply. Could you add a brief code snippet showing how to import and reexport pkgB::hello? I am not sure whether I understand correctly.

@LukasD.Sauer Ugh that took a minute and I discovered a bug in ‘roxygen2’. But this should now be fairly exhaustive.

Thanks a lot! Reexport is concept that I never heard of before. This is so helpful!

A workaround is changing Imports: to Depends: in the DESCRIPTION file, then both devtools::install() and devtools::check() worked without problems. The updated DESCRIPTION file reads as follows:
Package: pkgA
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Depends:
  pkgB
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.3.1

However, this is bad workaround, see here.

This is not a fix, it’s a (bad!) workaround. It’s bad, because “Depends:” attaches the dependency, which is (almost?) never appropriate. See https://github.com/leeper/Depends.

Thank you, @KonradRudolph -- I read that Depends is bad but it is the first thing that works. Do you have a better suggestion?

Actually I was completely puzzled by this behaviour but thanks to your complete example I was now able to reproduce the issue and figure out what caused it — see answer.
